# Substract column value in the next row with Decimal Output SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want retrieve the number of days in a decimal number every time the status is "Reviewed" and the ID number is the same, grouped by the ID.

This is how the table `Audit_Event` looks like:

```
ID           STATUS           EVENT_DATE
--           ------           ----------
1012         Fastrack         2018-05-24 10:07:46.560
1000         Reviewed         2018-05-25 12:35:07.023
1000         Declined         2018-06-15 21:02:32.567
1234         Cancelled        2018-05-01 13:00:35.257
1000         Reviewed         2018-06-16 10:46:41.607
1000         Completed        2018-06-20 13:08:27.697
2135         Approved         2018-06-20 16:18:27.240
1000         Cancelled        2018-06-27 15:11:33.930 
1035         Lead             2018-04-02 13:35:51.817
1000         Pre-Approval     2018-04-02 13:32:57.120
```

Taking the ID as an example = 1000 and the Status = Reviewed:

```
(2018-06-15 21:02:32.567 - 2018-05-25 12:35:07.023) + (2018-06-20 13:08:27.697 - 2018-06-16 10:46:41.607) = 25.45 (Days)
```

So the output should be:

```
ID            Number_Days
--------      ---------
1012           NULL
1000           25.45
1234           NULL
2135           NULL
```

This is the query I'm using right now:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Reviewed_Table', N'U') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #Reviewed_Table   

CREATE TABLE #Reviewed_Table
(
    RN INT,
    ID VARCHAR(50),
    EVENT_DATE DATETIME,
    STATUS VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #Reviewed_Table
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RN, 
        ID, EVENT_DATE, STATUS
    FROM 
        Audit_Event 


SELECT 
    T1.ID, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(16, 4), (SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.Event_Date, T2.Event_Date)))) Rev_Days
FROM 
    #Reviewed_Table T1  
LEFT JOIN 
    #Reviewed_Table T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN -1
WHERE 
    T1.STATUS = 'Reviewed' 
GROUP BY 
    T1.ID
```

Note: I can't use `LEAD` or `LAG` because this is a SQL Server 2008 machine.

If the status is different from `Reviewed` should be NULL. The status reviewed can be more than 2 and there are more possible states.

Any assistance or help would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking to the next record, then you can use `cross apply`:

```
select rt.id,
       ( datediff(second, rt.event_date, rt2.event_date) / (24 * 60 * 60.0) ) as number_days
from #Reviewed_Table rt outer apply
     (select top (1) rt2.*
      from #Reviewed_Table rt2
      where rt2.id = rt.id and rt2.event_date > rt.event_date
      order by rt2.event_date asc
     ) rt2
where rt.status = 'Reviewed'
group by rt.id;
```

Comment: Did you missed the comma after the rt.id ?

Comment: Is working great till now, how can I reduce the scale for the decimals into 2 digits like .00?

Comment: @JCACERES . . . You can cast to a `decimal(10, 2)` or use the `str()` function.